# Regular expression validation for telephone number

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am using the following regex for telephone number validation. It is allowing all the cases except one. 
 `^(\+?\ *[0-9]+)([0-9 ]*)([0-9 ])*$|(^ *$)` 
The conditions are
1. Allow numeric values
2. Allow plus sign only in the beginning 
The regex is getting failed while I enter the first character as plus sign. If I have entered a number after the plus sign it will work. My requirement is the form should valid while entering the plus sign as the first character. I am using a Angular reactive form. So error will fire entreating the first character itself. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend that you change your UI.  A good pattern to follow here would have separate boxes for each component in the phone number.  For starters, you could have a prefix box, which e.g. could either be empty or contain a single `+` sign.  Then, apply your number regex logic to a second box.

Comment: It does not work because this part `(\+?\ *[0-9]+)` expects at least 1 digit. Note that all that follows is optional and this part `(^ *$)` also matches an empty string. You might take a look at this page for [phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).

Comment: Just add `[+]?` after the carat `^` at the beginning. Here's an example cobbled from elsewhere on SO. https://regex101.com/r/SRMz4w/1

Comment: NB: the `([0-9 ])*` is useless. It will never capture anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `^(\+?)([0-9 ]*)([0-9 ])*$|(^ *$)`.

But what you had initially is also fine but as you said its not your requirement, try the above one